# Time ago in created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm trying to use

```
<%= comment.created_at.time_ago_in_words(from_time) %>
```

but it wont work. I want the comment to show date as: 3 minutes ago, or 2 days ago.

What is the correct way to use this helper?

In my layout helper:

```
def time_ago_in_words(from_time, include_seconds_or_options = {})
    distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, Time.now, include_seconds_or_options)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words

so it should be

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
```